# What is the reason for a bootstrap.css theme not working in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to change from the default theme in ASP.NET Core MVC. I am using the *Lumen* theme from https://bootswatch.com/ but it does not seem to be working correctly. Images attached below.

[image: top of page]
[image: footer of page]

I have added the theme as bootstrap-lumen.css in the `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\` directory and configured the `_Layout.cshtml` in the `Views\Shared\` directory to point to the bootstrap theme.

Both the theme and the ASP.NET Core MVC project are targeting the bootstrap version `3.3.7`.

*This question was made by a newbie of ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core so I apologise for any easy mistakes.*

Comment: Press f12 to se if you javascript files are uploaded.

Comment: All javascript files are status 304 (**Not Modified**) according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=devtools-netmonitor&utm_campaign=default.

Comment: Check jQuery file is uploaded and see in browser console what happens when you press the next button in your slide. Must have some error related with Jquery.

Comment: I see jQuery in the network tab but cant find anything updating in Visual Studio or the inspect element console. I am not good at the latter so that may be why im not seeing anything.

Comment: Check your path of the css and javascript files for misspelling.

Comment: Nope, there dont appear to be any mistakes :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maby It is because of the Bootstrap version differences!

The ASP.NET default template's Bootstrap version is 3.x.x and your chosen theme using Bootstrap version 4.x.x.

So you should replace latest Bootstrap (include css and js files) in your project.

If both version are same, use your web browser inspect and check if all of the css and JavaScript files are loaded successfully.

Remember that after any changing of your files, reload your web browser via `Ctrl+f5` for ignoring browser cache.

Comment: Looks like this was the answer but the Bootswatch website was wrong about the version in the CSS itself. Thanks!